# Showing old images in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table view that have an image of a movies poster but when I  scroll up and down the list I notices that it take few second to for the right poster to appear or that I have to scroll a little bit more until the correct image appear as you can see from the image below

[image]
 * if the image is black click on it to see it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableCell
            let entity = listOfMovies[indexPath.row]
            cell.movie = entity
            cell.movieTitle.text = entity.title
            cell.moviesReleaseDate.text = entity.releaseDate
            cell.voteAverage.text = "\(entity.voteAverage)"
            getMoviePoster(entity.backdropPath) { (image) in
                cell.moviePoster.image = image
            }


  func getMoviePoster(_ imagePath: String , completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage) -> Void ) -> Void {
        webserviceManager().getMoviePoster(imagePath:imagePath) { (success, image) in
            if success {
                completion(image!)
            }
        }
    }

    func getMoviePoster(imagePath:String, completion: @escaping (_ success:Bool, _ image:UIImage?) -> Void ) -> Void {
        if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet {
            let url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500\(imagePath)"
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseImage { (respones) in
                if respones.data != nil {
                    let webRespones = respones.result.value
                    completion (true,webRespones)
                } else {
                    completion (false,nil)
                }
            }
        } else {
            completion (false,nil)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Cells are reused. As you don't cache the images on each call of `cellForRow` the image is downloaded again and overwrites the previous displayed image. You need a logic which caches the images and associates them with the index paths.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused when you dequeue the cells fast, aka fast scrolling.

You can fix this simply by adding a default placeholder image or an empty one in your cell `prepareForReuse()` function, something like this.

```
  override func prepareForReuse() { // this is in my Custom Cell class
  imageView.image = UImage(named: "myPlaceholder") // this is will be called whenever you dequeue the cell . 
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't improve the user experience, instead of a *random* image you'll the see the placeholder.

Comment: This is the fix or this .. i don't understand whats your point .

Comment: This is not the fix. The point is that the images aren't cached. When the user scrolls you will see the placeholder and then after a short time the proper image. This will happen again and again. The fix is to cache the image to avoid continuous downloading of the images.

Comment: @vadian , aha i didn't thought about caching,  thanks for the insight .

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to add a property `image` to the data model

```
var image : UIImage?
```

In `cellForRow` check if the image exists. If it does display it, if not download it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableCell
    let entity = listOfMovies[indexPath.row]
    cell.movie = entity
    cell.movieTitle.text = entity.title
    cell.moviesReleaseDate.text = entity.releaseDate
    cell.voteAverage.text = "\(entity.voteAverage)"
    if let image = entity.image {
        cell.moviePoster.image = image
    } else {
        cell.moviePoster.image = nil
        getMoviePoster(entity.backdropPath) { (image) in
            listOfMovies[indexPath.row].image = image
            cell.moviePoster.image = image
        }
    }
```

However a better solution is a download manager which handles the case when a cell goes off-screen, and the solution doesn't work if cells can be inserted, deleted or moved.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer 
Just set the image view to nil in the beginning of cell for row at indexpath.
Added the Cell for row at indexpath code. Or you can add some placeholder image to show that the actual image is loading.

Here, you need to understand the concept of the the Reusable Cells in the table view, 
When you scroll, the cells from the top are reused, and shifted to the buttom of the for further use, so the data set in that cell UI should be reset.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableCell

            cell.moviePoster.image = nil

            let entity = listOfMovies[indexPath.row]
            cell.movie = entity
            cell.movieTitle.text = entity.title
            cell.moviesReleaseDate.text = entity.releaseDate
            cell.voteAverage.text = "\(entity.voteAverage)"
            getMoviePoster(entity.backdropPath) { (image) in
                cell.moviePoster.image = image
            }
```